# Recommended way to detect for Ajax support on mobile devices?

Tags: ajax, mobile

What is the standard method for detecting whether or not Ajax is supported on mobile devices? If it's not supported I need to replace Ajax content with static content. Did some Googling, but didn't find much.

Any suggestions or examples?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that there is necessarily a standard way--you can look at certain API/libraries/frameworks that use WURFL perhaps.

If WURFL is too heavyweight, here's what the UCLA Mobile Web Framework has developed thus far for it (ganked from https://github.com/ucla/mwf/blob/feature/core/root/assets/js/core/device.js):

```
/**
 * Determine if device supports AJAX. This attempts to create an XHR object
 * of the standard type and ActiveXObject varieties and, if any succeed, then
 * it returns true.
 */
this.hasAJAX = function(){
    var xhr = null;
    try { xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); } catch (e) {}
    try { xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e) {}
    try { xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e) {}
    return xhr != null;
}
```